# How to convert array data stored in a SQL Image column

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, binary-data

I have been asked to decompile an array of data that is stored within a SQL column with the image datatype. An example of the binary data is below.

```
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
```

As mentioned above, i was told this data is an array of integers of "X,Y" coordinates taken from another application used for graphic that were then shoved into this column.

I have attempted to cast this data but keep running into either data type conversion or explicit conversion errors. Some of my attempts are below.

```
SELECT
    CAST(DECOMPRESS(SurfaceCardB) AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS DataAsText 
FROM 
    [tblCardData]

SELECT
    CONVERT(xml, (CONVERT(varbinary(max), SurfaceCardB))) AS DataAsText 
FROM
    [tblCardData];
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I feel like it is something small that I am missing.

-------------UPDATE---------------

I made a little more progress using the following cast but it appears the XML is throwing an error.

```
cast(CONVERT(varbinary(MAX),[SurfaceCardB]) as XML)
```

Here is the error

```
Msg 9403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 0, character 0, unrecognized input signature
```

-------UPDATE 2--------------

The OG developer who is inserting this data finally responded to me and simply provided this statement(i held back my thoughts on his structure)

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), "myimagecolumn", 2) from "yourtable"
```

the problem is this also creates an explicit error within SQL. I'm going to push him for more information.

------Solution-----

The solution to convert from the image datatype to Varbinary to Varchar looks like this. This will work if your column data type is "IMAGE". I cannot stress enough to not use image in future databases.

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),(CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), [yourimagecolumn])) ,2) from [yourtable]  WHERE [atablecolumn] = 'something that you need'
```

This previous query provided to me also works IF* the column datatype in Varbinary from the start. My column was image which took extra steps.

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), "myimagecolumn", 2) from "yourtable"
```

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Converting from raw binary data to informational data is known as "decoding". Please describe the specific decoding algorithm do you want to use. It's not easy for us to guess it.

Comment: i do not believe the decoding part is necessary. I remember at one point in my career seeing a cast to XML being done on this column to view the data. However, i do not recall the data conversions that needed to be done to get it there. The problem i'm running into are the explicit errors while attempting to convert it. And i fully agree wtih Marcs comment about the image column type. I would not have designed this database this way.

Comment: do you have an example of the binary data and what you expect to get when decoding it?

Comment: Have you tried talking to the devs or technical leads for the application that's generating the data yet? Reading your words my first thought was "oh, that's probably WKB for geometry/geography types" but the header bytes are wrong.

Comment: I get the feeling you are missing something big (not small), that beeing how the binary data is encoded. You say this is an "array", but what makes you think this is an XML-array and not any other format? Also if this is XML you would need to know the character encoding (ASCII, Unicode). Just pasting this data as hex in a hex-encoder doesn't give anything that resembles text in a usual format.

Comment: Yeah you are probably right. I was able to reach the developer who designed the app who inserts this data (i held back my thoughts on this architecture). and he provided this convert statement.                                                                                            
       select CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), "myimagecolumn", 2) from yourtable                                         the problem is that it creates an explicit error within SQL